# SwiftUI Image does not display image from existing file

Tags: macos, swiftui, nsimage

In my SwiftUI app I have a view for people to edit a book's metadata, such as its title and author. In this view I have an image view that shows the book's cover image.

```
struct ImageView: View {

    @Binding var book: Book

    var body: some View {
        // coverFile is the URL to the image file.
        let image = NSImage(byReferencing: 
            book.metadata.coverFile)
        Image(nsImage: image)
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
    }
}
```

When I open a book that I've set a cover image and open the metadata editor, the image view displays nothing. The metadata editor has a button to choose a cover image. When I click the button and choose an image file from the file importer, the image appears in the image view. If I close the book, reopen it, and open the metadata editor, the image appears in the image view. But if I restart the app, open the book, and open the metadata editor, the image view displays nothing.

I have tried the various `NSImage` initializers. I tried building the image from a `Data` object and from `NSBitmapImageRep`.

```
extension Book {
    func coverImage() -> NSImage {
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: metadata.coverFile)
            return NSImage(data: data) ?? NSImage()
        } catch {
            Swift.print("Error reading the image data. Error: \(error)")
        }
        
        return NSImage()
    }
}

struct ImageView: View {
    @Binding var book: Book

    var body: some View {
        let image = book.coverImage()
        Image(nsImage: image)
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
    }
}
```

But when I set a breakpoint in the image view and check the `image` variable, it's either nil or invalid. When I check the `coverFile` variable, it displays the proper URL, including the `.png` extension.

In an AppKit version of this app, I have the same code to create the NSImage, and the image displays in the image view.

According to Apple's documentation, the `NSImage byReferencing` function does not attempt to retrieve the data from the specified URL or create any image representations from that data until an app attempts to draw the image or request information about it. How do I get the SwiftUI view to trigger retrieving the image data so it displays in the image view?

**UPDATE**

I created a computed property for the image in the `ImageView` struct.

```
var image: NSImage {
    do {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: book.metadata.coverFile)
        return NSImage(data: data) ?? NSImage()
    } catch {
        Swift.print("Error creating the image. Error: \(error)")
    }
        return NSImage()
}
```

When I run this code, the `try Data` call throws an exception, the `catch` block runs, and the following error message is printed in Xcode's Console:

> Error creating the image. Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain
> Code=257 "The file “ImageFile” couldn’t be opened because you
> don’t have permission to view it."

Choosing a file from the file importer causes the data to be created properly. I have read/write permission for the folder where the image file is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image does not display because of a file permissions problem. If I turn on the App Sandbox and give the app Read access to the Pictures folder, the cover image appears when I open the metadata editor.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand the problem boils down to lazily initializing the NSImage.

Have you tried using init(contentsOfFile:) or init(contentsOf:)? It does not initialize it lazily therefore should not cause this problem.

Comment: The topic is for macOS, NSImage is part of AppKit, UIImage is iOS only.

Comment: It's a multiplatform project so I need NSImage for the Mac version. I'm using UIImage for the iOS version.

Comment: @SwiftDevJournal Have you tried using init(contentsOfFile:) or init(contentsOf:)? It does not initialize it lazily therefore should not cause this problem.

Comment: Yes I have. No matter what init I use the image is either nil or invalid.

Comment: @SwiftDevJournal This is weird. Are you sure the URL is valid? As in how are you creating said URL? Can you post the code of what executes when you "click the button and choose an image file from the file importer"?

Comment: The URL is valid. When I choose an image file from the file importer, I set the `coverFile` variable to the URL of the selected file from the file importer. `book.metadata.coverFile = url`

Comment: @SwiftDevJournal maybe it's the problem with the way the body is calculated... Have you tried moving your 'let image = book.coverImage()' outside of the body and maybe making it a State variable?

Comment: I get a compiler error if I do the following: `@State var imageURL = book.metadata.coverFile`. The error message is "Cannot use instance member 'book' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available". I have also tried adding a property for the NSImage in the `Book` struct. But the image does not appear until I explicitly set it from the file importer.

Comment: @SwiftDevJournal yeah you can't do it just like that. Try assigning it at init block. After declaring your properties: 
init(_ b: Binding<Book>)  { self._book = b; self.imageURL = b.wrappedValue.metadata.coverFile }

Comment: The image is still invalid or nil with a @State property whose value is assigned in an init block.

Comment: @SwiftDevJournal Have you tried checking it without property wrappers? Otherwise I give up. It doesn't make any sense unless the initial URL broken somehow.